# How to connect to Soundcloud in Tizonia?

Tags: linux, debian-bullseye, music-streaming, tizonia

I want to connect my Tizonia player installation to Soundcloud.

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.tizonia.org/manual/soundcloud.html), it is suggested to hit that "Connect with Soundcloud" button, which leads to a dubious site with no interface, asking to sign in. Is it legitimate? I just need to know how to get an access token. After that, I know how to put it in the config file and everything.

I'm running the most recent (as of 2022-12-15) Snap package of Tizonia on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Comment: What is the URL of the site you're taken to? What credentials is it looking for?

Comment: @music2myear Thanks for your comment. www.aratelia.com/index.php/open-source/77-main/88-connect-with-soundcloud# is the URL I'm taken to. I get a generic Firefox pop-up saying that "This site is asking you to sign in." I guess it wants my Soundcloud credentials, but it's not the Soundcloud site, so I don't know. If I just try to go to aratelia.com and see what it looks like, I still get that sign-in popup, and I'm never shown an actual webpage.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question. Use the edit button to improve your question rather than adding comments here.